# AngularJS load select options when the control get focus

Tags: angularjs

I want to make my page a little lighter weight. I have some elements that have to be select options but I need them to load just as the user touches the control. Maybe display a loading dialog for a split second to give them feedback. How can I do this in Angular? I tried ng-click and ng-focus to trigger the model option population but it never fires.

```
<select name="Category"  ng-model="selectedCategory" ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in     categories">
        <option value="" disabled selected>All Categories</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-focus` should work.  Just let `$scope.categories` start out as an empty array, and populate it in your `ng-focus` function:

```
$scope.categories = [];
$scope.selectedCategory = {};

$scope.loadOptions = function() {
  if ($scope.categories.length == 0) {
    $scope.categories = [{
      name: 'option1'
    }, {
      name: 'option2'
    }, {
      name: 'option3'
    }];
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select name="Category" ng-model="selectedCategory" 
  ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in categories" 
  ng-focus="loadOptions()">
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TMmcZj1hiFmIDY3gfqnm)

Comment: I guess I did something wrong the first time with focus... I do have an issue though. The select doesn't refresh after the data is loaded. I have to click off the select and back on it... Is there any easy way to get it to refresh without user interaction?

Comment: Ah yes, if you are loading your options from an external source, they won't be there in time before the dropdown expands.  I'm not sure if there's anything to be done there.  It feels like a browser limitation (it doesn't redraw the options while the list is expanded).  You may need to look into a JQuery-based select box like [ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2).  They have demos of the dropdown dynamically loading options.